# How to make tab automatically blink when custom alert box comes on a webpage while user is on another tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to make functioning as same as default alert box blink behavior while user is on another tab.

Comment: You could animate the title text.

Comment: notification api FTW https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification